# How to access class items in beautifulsoup . below i have data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The above is the httml code im accessing, i need to gather data of "data-vehicle"

Below is my code, it wont print anything, it only prints content list variable

```
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
content_list = html_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'vehicle vehicle-grid-item'})
print(content_list)

basic_info = []
for item in content_list:
    basic_info.append(item.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'data-vehicle'}))
print(basic_info)
```

it wont print basic_info variable

Comment: <div class="vehicle vehicle-grid-item" data-auto5-vehicle-vin="3N1AB7AP1KY453039" data-vehicle='{"year":"2019","make":"Nissan","model":"Sentra","trim":"SV CVT","bodyType":["Sedan"],"fuelType":"Gasoline","vin":"3N1AB7AP1KY453039","exterior_color":"Blue","drivetrain":"Front Wheel Drive","transmission":"1-Speed CVT w\/OD","zip":"76210","conditions":["Used"],"condition":"used","mileage":62818,"price":"17,999","stockNumber":"7TW77W","location":{"name":"Enterprise Car Sales Corinth"}}'>
this is the html code i was talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*data-vehicle* is an attribute of the div element that can be accessed with `item.get("data-vehicle")`.

```python
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<html>
<div class="vehicle vehicle-grid-item" data-auto5-vehicle-vin="3N1AB7AP1KY453039"
 data-vehicle='{"year":"2019","make":"Nissan","model":"Sentra","trim":"SV CVT","bodyType":["Sedan"],"fuelType":"Gasoline","vin":"3N1AB7AP1KY453039","exterior_color":"Blue","drivetrain":"Front Wheel Drive","transmission":"1-Speed CVT w\/OD","zip":"76210","conditions":["Used"],"condition":"used","mileage":62818,"price":"17,999","stockNumber":"7TW77W","location":{"name":"Enterprise Car Sales Corinth"}}'/>
<div class="vehicle vehicle-grid-item" data-vehicle='{"year":"2019","make":"Ford","model":"Fiesta","bodyType":["Sedan"],"fuelType":"Gasoline","condition":"used"}'/>
</html>
'''

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content_list = html_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'vehicle vehicle-grid-item'})
# print(content_list)

basic_info = []
for item in content_list:
    data = item.get("data-vehicle")
    if data:
        # next convert the JSON string content to a dictionary
        # so can create a dataframe with data-vehicle fields in each row
        # location is a nested dictionary
        if "location" in data:
            location = data.pop("location")
            for k, v in location.items():
                data[f"location.{k}"] = v
        basic_info.append(json.loads(data))
print(basic_info)

# convert to a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(basic_info)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'year': '2019', 'make': 'Nissan', 'model': 'Sentra', 'trim': 'SV CVT',
'bodyType': ['Sedan'], 'fuelType': 'Gasoline', 'vin': '3N1AB7AP1KY453039',
'exterior_color': 'Blue', 'drivetrain': 'Front Wheel Drive',
'transmission': '1-Speed CVT w/OD', 'zip': '76210', 'conditions': ['Used'],
'condition': 'used', 'mileage': 62818, 'price': '17,999', 'stockNumber': '7TW77W',
'location.name': 'Enterprise Car Sales Corinth'}...]

   year    make   model    trim bodyType  fuelType                vin  ...    zip conditions condition  mileage   price stockNumber                 location.name
0  2019  Nissan  Sentra  SV CVT  [Sedan]  Gasoline  3N1AB7AP1KY453039  ...  76210     [Used]      used  62818.0  17,999      7TW77W  Enterprise Car Sales Corinth
1  2019    Ford  Fiesta     NaN  [Sedan]  Gasoline                NaN  ...    NaN        NaN      used      NaN     NaN         NaN                           NaN

[2 rows x 17 columns]
```

You can also create the dataframe with [pd.DataFrame.from_records()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).

Comment: how do i extract year,make,model etc and create a dataframe from the result of variable basic_info?

Comment: @harsha2204 see updated answer to create a dataframe from it

Comment: 0
0 {"year":"2019","make":"Ford","model":"Fiesta",...
1 {"year":"2018","make":"Chevrolet","model":"Tra...
2 {"year":"2019","make":"Nissan","model":"Sentra...
3 {"year":"2019","make":"Nissan","model":"Sentra...
4 {"year":"2019","make":"Nissan","model":"Sentra...
5 {"year":"2015","make":"Jeep","model":"Cherokee...
6 {"year":"2019","make":"Hyundai","model":"Tucso...
the output looks like this..how to get year,make,model as columns?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(basic_info)`

Comment: Thank you so much i got my desired answer